# Print matching values between csv file and website

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I want to match the row [1] which is the Addresses field in the csv file to the website below. I want Python to search for each Address value in the csv file and bring back whatever data is made available pertinent to the Address on the website. Is it possible?

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv

r = requests.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')

with open ('C:/Users/Pythoner/Addresses.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

if row[1] is a url you could try

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv

with open ('C:/Users/Pythoner/Addresses.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        r = requests.get(row[1])
        print r.text
```

look at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python for help learning how to use the Requests library